# Recording audio with additional binary/text data

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.android, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I want my android application **record live audio from microphone and add my own binary data as image frames**. I will be recording board game and whole image can be saved to around 50 bytes. The content should be possible to stream online so I want to put the data to some standard media container.

I checked various classes but can't build it together.

In `MediaRecorder` and `AudioRecord` classes I miss functions to add any sort of special data / tracks.

In `MediaMuxer` I can't find on the other hand a way how to record live, seems to me it only combines existing tracks.

Am I missing something in classes mentioned above? Or can this thing be done with `MediaCodec` and `MediaExtractor`? I don't much understand how these should be used.

Link to existing code would be welcome, I can check on my own, I just don't know where to search for the answer.

Comment: you start off talking about audio but then talk about adding "images" to it...you mean you want a video, or what? It's unclear.

Comment: @ADyson The actual image should be built from couple of bytes of extra data I'm trying to store to the content for streaming. Something like 64 bytes for chess board state. I don't want to store any standard picture data, just audio data and game data. Wasn't sure whether to call it audio or video...

Comment: well audio files inherently don't contain images....they're audio-only, by definition. I'd guess you maybe want a video which displays the same thing all the way through. I don't know, it's not really clear what you think the picture is for. "for streaming" is a vague description...what platform are you talking about hosting it on?

Comment: @ADyson The game data will be changing as it will be for showing chess content live. I want to stream live broadcast to CDN I'm using (CDN77). The content is supposed to be readable only by my application again, due to need to build image from game data in my own format...

Comment: so basically you want to record what's on the screen of the device and add some audio over the top of it from the microphone? And then send the recording to the CDN afterwards? Or live-stream it perhaps?

Comment: @ADyson I want to record audio and current board state of my game so yes, I want a video. The game state will be taken from internal chess board. I will not be parsing any image data. I want to make the compression based on game data.